# Global regex substitution AND storing

Tags: regex, perl

I need to replace all matchings of some pattern and keep their old values into an array. I can manage it in two steps, in a such way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@num = ();

$_ = "We had 2 bags of grass, 75 pellets of mescaline, 
5 sheets of high powered blotter acid, a salt shaker 0.5 full of cocaine,
and a 1.0 galaxy of multi-colored uppers, downers, screamers, laughers...
and also a 0.25gal of tequila, a 0.25gal of rum, a case of Budweiser,
a 0.125gal of raw ether and 24 amyls.";

s/\d+(\.\d*)?/push(@num, $&)/ge;  # Step 1: Store
s/\d+(\.\d*)?/some/g;             # Step 2: Replace

print "@num";                     # 2 75 5 0.5 1.0 0.25 0.25 0.125 24
print "$_";                       # We had some bags of grass, ...
```

But I believe it's not good: actually, the same code is typed twice. I would prefer a single regex as solution of the problem. Is that possible in Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been substituting with return value of push ([Returns the number of elements in the array following the completed push.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html)), so you need to correct last expression in substitution.

```
s/\d+(\.\d*)?/ push(@num, $&); "some" /ge;
```

Side note; as `$&` [imposes a performance penalty](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24&) you can also

```
s/(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)/ push(@num, $1); "some" /ge;
```

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that the OP's code doesn't actually work the way (s)he thinks it does; `push` returns the number of elements that were pushed, which in this case is always `1`, so the first line stores the number *and* replaces it with `1`, and then the second line replaces the `1` with `some`.

Answer (score 1):

As you'll see, the last statement in the right side of the regex is what is used to substitute.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = ();

my $text = "We had 2 bags of grass, 75 pellets of mescaline, 
5 sheets of high powered blotter acid, a salt shaker 0.5 full of cocaine,
and a 1.0 galaxy of multi-colored uppers, downers, screamers, laughers...
and also a 0.25gal of tequila, a 0.25gal of rum, a case of Budweiser,
a 0.125gal of raw ether and 24 amyls.";

$text =~ s{(\d+\.?\d*)}{
    push(@nums, $1);
    "some"
}ge;

print "@nums\n";                     # 2 75 5 0.5 1.0 0.25 0.25 0.125 24
print "$text";
```